# ToogleButton align text label on the right

Tags: android

I want to align the text in a `ToogleButton` on the right of that bar that became green/white when pressing it.

To be more explicit I will post the code and also the result I have now.

```
 <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/ToggleButton01"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                  android:textOff="Off"
              android:textOn="On"/>

 ToggleButton onOffButton = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.ToggleButton01);
 onOffButton.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
 onOffButton.setPadding(0, 0, 5, 0);
```

and the result:
[image]

I want the bar and the text to not be overlapped.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried the attibute gravity?

```
android:gravity="center"
```

the diference between `android:layout_gravity="center"` and `android:gravity="center"` is that the first one will center your `View` within your `layout` and the second will center the content of that `View`.

This is my layout of your button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/ToggleButton01"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                  android:textOff="Off"
                  android:gravity="center"
              android:textOn="On"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: well, I tested it so perhaps you are overriding the value somewhere on your code.

Comment: is not working...basically what I want (because maybe I did not expressed sufficiently precise) is the text to be horizontally aligned with that green line (the text - On/Off to be at the right of that green line).

Comment: oh if what you want is the text right of the green bar then thats not possible, unless perhaps making your own implementation of ToggleButton.

Comment: other way that might be easier rather than making your own implementation of ToggleButton is to apply a style to your button like this: http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/07/sexily-styled-toggle-buttons-for-android/ and then you can draw the text at the right, or use other things as you please.
Sorry for the missunderstanding btw :)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I've tried also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827437/togglebutton-text-label-placement-for-on-and-off-state but this isn't referring of placing the text on the right side of the green line, but instead on the right side above the green line. I'll try the example you provided also. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you are looking at `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/the_button_resource"`

There are other options like drawableRight/drawableTop/drawableBottom that places drawable resource at the param suggests

Comment: Please be noted that the toggle color state changes has to be handled in state xml - ie (the_button_resource) contains what resource to use when in "pressed_state", " on_state" etc.