# Android Switch TextOn/TextOff Placement

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have set the text for my switch, however it is displayed inside the slider like this:
[image]

How can I get it shown below the switch instead?

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="false"
            android:theme="@style/Switch"
            android:textOn="ON"
            android:textOff="OFF"
            app:showText="true"
            />
```

Comment: try to use gravity and paddings like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827437/togglebutton-text-label-placement-for-on-and-off-state